# Can't use 'jsonschema2pojo' gradle plugin in plugins {} block?

Tags: java, json, gradle

Anyone can explain where to get the `id` of that plugin and why I can't use it in `plugins{}` ?

I want to start using this

```
plugins {
    id "jsonschema2pojo" version "0.5.1"
}
```

but instead, I'm forced to use the old way of applying plugins with `buildscript`

I cant use both as those are excluding each other.

here's the question I asked on GitHub
https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/issues/896#issuecomment-411491416

If not possible anyone know a better/different gradle plugin to achieve this?

Comment: See https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/issues/282

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a while I managed to make it work with:

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id "org.jsonschema2pojo.gradle" version "1.0.0-alpha2"
}
```

as `jsonschema2pojo` return a null `id.namespace` this `org.jsonschema2pojo.gradle` returns a `org.jsonschema2pojo` `id.namespace` and we can use then a resulution strategy.

**settings.gradle**

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        maven { url ".../nexus/content/groups/GradlePlugins/" }
        maven { url ".../nexus/content/groups/public/" }
    }
    resolutionStrategy {
        eachPlugin {
            if (requested.id.namespace == 'org.jsonschema2pojo') {
                useModule("org.jsonschema2pojo:jsonschema2pojo-gradle-plugin:$requested.version")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that will help someone it's not the cleanest but it works.

Comment: You've declared the same version twice, if it were me I'd investigate how to declare the version only in one place. Possibly `useModule("org.jsonschema2pojo:jsonschema2pojo-gradle-plugin:$requested.version")`

Comment: I'd do it differently by requiring a version in the `plugins {...}` block which is used by the resolution strategy. See my comment

Comment: That's even better! Thanks Lance :)

Comment: @lance-java can you share your solution?

Comment: @LazerBanana what's the nexus/content/... stuff for?  Do you need that to make this work?

Comment: How did you find your plugin id, I'm getting
Could not apply requested plugin [id: 'org.jsonschema2pojo.gradle', version: '1.0.2', artifact: 'org.jsonschema2pojo:jsonschema2pojo-gradle-plugin:1.0.2'] as it does not provide a plugin with id 'org.jsonschema2pojo.gradle'. This is caused by an incorrect plugin implementation. Please contact the plugin author(s).
> Plugin with id 'org.jsonschema2pojo.gradle' not found.

Comment: The following issues are relevant: 
https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/issues/282
https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/issues/896
Please vote.

Answer (score 1):

I can see from [this file](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/blob/master/jsonschema2pojo-gradle-plugin/src/main/resources/META-INF/gradle-plugins/jsonschema2pojo.properties) that the id is jsonschema2pojo

But [searching the gradle plugin portal](https://plugins.gradle.org/search?term=jsonschema2pojo) returns zero results for that plugin so you will need to find where it is hosted. See [custom plugin repositories](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:custom_plugin_repositories)

Eg settings.gradle

```
pluginManagement {
  repositories {
      maven {
        url 'maven-repo'
      }
      gradlePluginPortal()
      ivy {
        url 'ivy-repo'
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah, I have added few repos Lance, i think I'm just going to download the whole plugin and upload it manually to my nexus.

Comment: I can see it on Maven Central [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.jsonschema2pojo/jsonschema2pojo-gradle-plugin/1.0.0-alpha4/jar)

Comment: yeah, the readme states that its there but we block Maven central. Thanks for looking any way ;)

Comment: Are you sure you block it? I'm guessing you have a nexus repository which proxies through to Maven Central

Comment: yes exactly but for some unknown for me reason, it can't find it. 
plugin [id: 'jsonschema2pojo', version: '0.5.1', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

maven(.../nexus/content/groups/GradlePlugins/)
maven2(.../nexus/content/groups/public/)

Comment: It seems that this plugin is built by maven (see [here](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/blob/master/jsonschema2pojo-gradle-plugin/pom.xml)). Guessing its not using the normal gradle publishing mechanisms

Comment: Yes, this is what we found out as well after checking the code base, and also this is what the author stated after I spoke to him on GitHub. I'm going to try to contribute and fix it. Also is a tree of poms essentially.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [jsonschema2pojo plugin repo](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/tree/master/jsonschema2pojo-gradle-plugin/src/main/resources/META-INF/gradle-plugins), the id has to be `jsonschema2pojo` and we need to change the `group` & `name` so gradle can find it:

**gradle.properties**

I use properties for all versions

```
versions.org.jsonschema2pojo=1.1.2
```

**settings.gradle**

- Use Maven Central & Gradle Plugin Portal for plugins
- Change the group & name so gradle can find it

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }

    plugins {
       // other plugin versions
       id 'com.github.ben-manes.versions' version getProperty('versions.com.github.ben.manes.versions')        
    }

    resolutionStrategy {
        eachPlugin {
            if (requested.id.name == 'jsonschema2pojo') {
                useModule group: 'org.jsonschema2pojo',
                          name: 'jsonschema2pojo-gradle-plugin',
                          version: getProperty('versions.org.jsonschema2pojo')
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**build.gradle**

Only the plugin id is required, as we've set the version in `settings.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    // external plugin versions are in settings.gradle
    id 'com.github.ben-manes.versions'
    ...
    id 'jsonschema2pojo'
}
```